# Set kubernetes VM with nodeports as backend for application gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-gateway

I have two VMs that are part of a kubernetes cluster. I have a single service that is exposed as NodePort (30001). I am able to reach this service on port 30001 through curl on each of these VMs. When I create an Azure application gateway, the gateway is not directing traffic to these VMs.

I've followed the steps for setting up the application gateway as listed in the Azure documentation.

I constantly get a 502 from the gateway.

Comment: Please start with [troubleshooting section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502)

Comment: @hanx - tried that as well. Doesn't solve the problem. There seems to be something funny the application gateway is doing if the target VM in the backend pools are kubernetes nodes with nodePort exposed. Have raised a support ticket - will update this question if tech support is able to solve this problem

Comment: How do you configure the Azure application gateway to access the service in the AKS cluster?

Comment: @CharlesXu : I tried using AKS and application gateway as well, but it was so complex, that I ended up using a handcrafted K3S cluster (I don't need persistent volumes etc) fronted by a L4 load balancer and all the path based routing using ingress-nginx. Advantage is that all my configuration is code that is checked into a repository as opposed to hanging around in application gateway. It has worked out pretty well - happy to share my experiences if it is of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally ended up getting on a call with the support folks. It turned out that the UI on Azure's portal is slightly tempremental.

For the gateway to be able to determine which of your backends are healthy it needs to have a health probe associated with the HTTP setting (the HTTP Setting is the one that determines how traffic from the gateway flows to your backends).

Now, when you are configuring the HTTP setting, you need to select the "Use Custom Probe" but when you do that it doesn't show the probe that you have already created. Hence, I figured that wasn't required.

The trick to first check the box below "Use Custom probe" which reads "Pick hostname from backend setttings", and then click on custom probe and your custom probe will show up and things will work.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Azure Application Gateway to redirect or route traffic to the NodePort you need to add the Backend servers to the backend pool inside the Azure Application Gateway.
There are options to choose Virtual Machines as well.

A good tutorial explaining how to configure an application gateway in azure and direct web traffic to the backend pool is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Once you brief the contents of the link, it is better for the questioner.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I added the contents of the link.

Comment: @ali - already tried all of the tutorials and documentation. Doesn't work if the vms in question are part of a kubernetes cluster and exposing nodePorts. If you've tried my scenario yourself and gotten it to work, let me know how you did it.